# Any documentation or examples i can refer for building integrations using WSO2?

Tags: wso2-esb

I am looking for a help in locating documentation/material which can help me in creating integrations using WSO2 developer studio

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be helpful,
https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action?dest=%23page%2F45970439

And also you can always follow WSO2 Documentation and it will contain code snippets with explanations. You can copy and paste it in code view and then if you switch to design view, you will be able to see the mediation and understand what’s happening.
https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/87712889

Answer (score 0):

There is also a set of self-paced training materials. Currently they are available [here](https://wso2.com/training#SelfPacedTraining)